# Why does this use of Random in a function cause repeats?

Tags: scala, random

Below is some really rudimentary sample code to illustrate the question.

```
case class randomizer(seed: Long){
  def getRandom(): Double = {
    //Other stuff
    val rand = new util.Random(seed)
    rand.nextDouble()
  }
}
```

This will reliably return the same first value always. Every time getRandom is called.

However,

```
case class randomizer(seed: Long){
  val rand = new util.Random(seed)

  def getRandom(): Double = {
    //Other stuff

    rand.nextDouble()
  }
}
```

This will return a different random value every time.

I suspect this is because by re-initializing rand every single time (as in the first one) we end up getting the first number for that seed. Since the seed guarantees that we will get the same "set" of random numbers each time this is expected behavior. By moving the generator outside of the function it will exist as long as the class does, and as a result continue generating numbers in that "set". Is this the correct way to think about this?

Comment: <Insert weekly "don't seed the RNG inside your loop" answer here>

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Thanks for that. I really appreciate your bitter snark in reply to an honest question.

Comment: It really is about once a week, despite being well-documented and easily searchable. Along with the weekly "You can't use ++ like that" and "char literals are immutable" questions. You'll get cynical after 30 years, too.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker That's what I'd expect from a programmer who feels smugly superior to everyone else. You're exactly what's wrong with this industry. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a "set" so much as a "stream", but yes, that's it.